# Docker in WSL2: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://localhost:2375. Is the docker daemon running?

Tags: docker, debian, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I am currently running a Debian Distro (The default one from the Microsoft Store) on WSL 2 and I am having a lot of trouble with running Docker on it. My OS currently is Windows 10 Education Insider Preview, version 2004, and the os build is 19587.1000 and I have Docker Desktop.

Now, at this point, I've literally tried everything. I have tried using the "Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS" way to no result. Then, I tried enabling "Enable the experimental WSL 2 based engine" (this is also why I had to move to Windows 10 education and get docker desktop and move to this version 2004). 
I have also commented out "#export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://localhost:2375" from my .bashrc.
And then since WSL does not support systemd nor systemctl, starting docker using these are useless, and thus I tried "sudo service docker start" and also "sudo /etc/init.d/docker start". But, still when I run any command in Docker in my WSL, it gives me this:

```
$ docker ps -a 
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://localhost:2375. Is the docker daemon running?
```

I just can't seem to figure out what is wrong...
I've looked up everywhere, tutorials, forums, other questions on StackOverFlow.
Most are either about Docker on Native Linux or on WSL 1 where they use the first method of exposing the daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS which is not very secure, but I didn't even get that working on mine.

Please help! It would be greatly appreciated!!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so basically I installed a clean WSL. This time I got a clean Ubuntu, and somehow it fixed the issue. My other WSL distros still won't work with this, but this clean Ubuntu does. However, as soon as I installed some stuff on it, it started breaking again. Now, I reinstalled it and now it works fine. Seems like something could be potentially conflicting with this?

Comment: With WSL2, I think you don't ned to check "Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS". Am I right ?

Comment: yes if you have the docker hub, you just need to turn the feature on now.

Answer (score 22):

https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/5096

Make sure youve upgraded your wsl distro to v2 by checking  `wsl -l -v` in windows powershell

In docker settings, Use the WSL 2 based engine & Enable WSL integration for your distro [image: Docker settings]

But what finally fixed it for me was overriding the `DOCKER_HOST` env variable left over from using WSL1

`export DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock`

You can execute this line to test and then add it to your `.bashrc` and make sure its not getting set in `.bash_profile` or`.profile`

You should then be able to run `docker ps` successfully

Comment: To convert into version 2 
wsl --set-version <Distro> 2

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I am using WSL2 + Ubuntu + Docker Desktop. What fixed the issue for me was[checking the option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5c3E.png) "Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS" in Docker Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on Debian, which was strange, as I had a running instance of OpenSUSE connecting to and using docker without problems.
In my case the reported error was
`Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`

WSL2 Integration was enabled for both instances.

What eventually worked was the following:

1. From within both WSL Debian and WSL.exe - `unset DOCKER_HOST`
2. Restart Docker... (right-click on the Docker Dashboard icon in Task Bar)
3. Try any docker command again or just plain `docker ps`

There *is* an option for exposing the daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS, however it is unchecked by default, and I left it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling virtualization technology in the bios settings worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).